# Modal bootstrap para editar cadastros no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, modal, laravel-blade

Olá, sou iniciante na programação PHP/Laravel e gostaria de incluir um modal para o cadastro e edição de registros do banco de dados. Segue o exemplo:

Na minha index.blade.php eu tenho:

```html
@extends('app.layouts.basic')

@section('title', 'Liste de Clients')

@section('contenu')

<div class="col text-center" style="padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px">
  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('client.create') }}" role="button">Ajouter nouveau client</a>
</div>

<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Code</th>
        <th scope="col">Nom</th>
        <th scope="col">tva</th>
        <th scope="col">Adresse</th>
        <th scope="col">Code Postale</th>
        <th scope="col">Ville</th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      @foreach ($clients as $client )
      <tr>
        <td>{{ $client->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $client->nom }}</td>
        <td>{{ $client->tva }}</td>
        <td>{{ $client->adresse }}</td>
        <td>{{ $client->cp }}</td>
        <td>{{ $client->ville }}</td>
        <td><a href="{{ route('client.edit', $client->id ) }}"<i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
      {{ $clients->appends($request)->links() }}
    </ul>
  </nav>
  
  <div style="text-align: center">
  Resultats {{ $clients->count() }} sur {{ $clients->total() }} ({{ $clients->firstItem() }} à {{ $clients->lastItem() }})
  </div>

@endsection
```

Em minha página edit.blade.php:

```html
@extends('app.layouts.basic')


@section('title', 'Ajouter un nouveau client')

@section('contenu')

  <div class="container">
    <form action='' method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $clients->id }}">
      @csrf
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="inputNom">Nom</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nom" value="{{  $clients->nom ?? old('nom') }}" id="inputNom" placeholder="Construart SPRL">
          {{ $errors->has('nom') ? $errors->first('nom') : '' }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="inputTva">TVA</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="tva" value="{{  $clients->tva ?? old('tva') }}" id="inputTva" placeholder="BE08 2139 0852">
          {{ $errors->has('tva') ? $errors->first('tva') : '' }}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label for="inputPays">Pays</label>
          <select name="pays_id" id="inputPays" class="form-control">

            @foreach ($pays as $pays)
            <option value="{{ $pays->id }}" {{ ( $clients->pays_id ?? old('pays_id')) == $pays->id ? 'selected' : ''}} >{{ $pays->nompays }}</option>
            @endforeach

          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
          <label for="inputCp">CP</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cp" value="{{ $clients->cp ?? old('cp') }}" id="inputCp" placeholder="1930">
          {{ $errors->has('cp') ? $errors->first('cp') : '' }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="inputVille">Ville</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ville" value="{{ $clients->ville ??  old('ville') }}" id="inputVille" placeholder="Zaventem">
          {{ $errors->has('ville') ? $errors->first('ville') : '' }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputAddresse">Addresse</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="adresse" value="{{  $clients->adresse ?? old('adresse') }}" id="inputAddresse" placeholder="Excelsiorlaan 16">
        {{ $errors->has('adresse') ? $errors->first('adresse') : '' }}
      </div>
      <div class="custom-control custom-switch">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="activation" id="activation" value="2">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="activation">Active?</label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enregistrer</button>
    </form>
  </div>

@endsection
```

Em resumo, gostaria que abrisse a modal com o conteúdo do edit.blade.php.

Obs: Já tenho o bootstrap e Jquery na @extends('app.layouts.basic') e está funcionando perfeitamente, só não encontrei a receita para executar a modal.

Obrigado por sua atenção.

Answer (score -1):

Bom pelo que eu entendi, seu problema é apenas como exibir um modal, aqui abaixo, segue um exemplo, de como exibir um modal, apenas ao clicar em um botão. Para exibir seu conteúdo dentro, você só preciso uncluir seu formulário dentro do local "Cola o código aqui":

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
           <div class="modal-content">
            Cola o código html aqui
          </div>
    </div>
```

Mais informações sobre formulários: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Comment: Me desculpe, acho que eu me expressei mal.

Minha intenção é que ao clicar em editar ele chame a modal com o form para edição mas sem que eu tenha todo o código do modal na página index. Para que fique com o código mais organizado. 

Eu acredito que seja usando as funções yeld section... mas não consegui chegar a solução.